# URL redirect module working fine with nodes not with alias url's

Tags: 7, redirection

I am new to Drupal. I have installed URL [Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module and tried the following.

Source URL: testwebsite.com/how

Redirect URL: testwebsite.com/how-to-do

Its get stored with node id instead actual URL.

Source URL: http://www.testwebsite.com/node/123545

Redirect URL: http://www.testwebsite.com/node/134566

When I tried to call with node URL its redirecting fine. But when I call testwebsite.com/how it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Path Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module in your scenario. Module page says :

> This module allows you to specify a redirect from one path to another
>   path or an external URL, using any HTTP redirect status.

Comment: But i am having drupal 7 and i think Path Redirect module supports drupal 6

Comment: Redirect is the new namespace for Path Redirect in D7.

Comment: Yes, but did you get my issue? in redirect module only i am having issue.